# InfoPath form on add new item throwing amount of data returned by data connection exceeded

Tags: infopath-data-connections

The amount of data that was returned by a data connection has exceeded the maximum limit that was configured by the server administrator. Form elements, such as drop-down lists, may be blank.

This list does not have single item and it is a new list. When i try to add item it is throwing the above error. Any idea r suggestions on how to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps Followed

1. Go to Central Administration
2. go to general settings
3. Under InfoPath form services click on Configure InfoPath form services
4. Data connection response time default value is 1500KB changed it to 21000
   Now the forms are opening normally.

Comment: Hi @user2314241 If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Comment: Hi Qassas I can mark it only after 24 hours. I will definitely do that. Thank you qassas.

Answer (score 1):

Your InfoPath Form Data connection is running on load and getting a drop down data field from a secondary data connection. Open the form in design and make sure where are you pulling the data from. You might want to add filters in your query so you should pull the specific data not all the items in a list.

Alternate Solution: Increase List Item threshold limit from 5000 to 10000 and that should solve the data connection time out issue.

Comment: Hi Noman where do you want me to add the filters?

Comment: 1) Go to InfoPath Form, edit mode
2) Edit the data connection and make sure it doesn't run on form load
3) Within your form rules, add a rule to set the query field of your data connection. This is where you will add filters.
4) Then run your data connection

Comment: Hi Noman it did not worked.. do you have any idea on data connection response time? does increasing the data connection response time from central administration resolve this and is it recommended ?

Comment: Data connection response time is based of off your list threshold, which is usually 5000. You may try to increase the list threshold limit to a higher number if that solves your issue.

Comment: Data connection response time has worked.

Comment: Great, I am glad it solved the problem.

Comment: But did not change the thresh hold limit instead changed the  response time in central administration.